# How to add `Type` field to `Event` object

Tags: picklist, event

I am trying to add `Type` field to the `Event` object ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm ) object.

I have tried the following code:

```
List<PicklistValue> picklistValues = new ArrayList<>();
    PicklistValue value = new PicklistValue();
    value.setFullName("Meeting");
    picklistValues.add(value);
    Picklist picklist = new Picklist();
    picklist.setPicklistValues(picklistValues.toArray(new PicklistValue[picklistValues.size()]));
    sfdcEventRecord.set("Type", picklist);
```

but I get the followig exception when trying connect with the client:
`clients.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://ringdna3-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0`.  Also, I am not sure if this is the correct type of the picklist, but was not able to find another one.enter code here

If I remove code above I can post Event object.  Thus I think the error is related to validation of the added field.

Comment: What is the type of `sfdcEventRecord`? Are you making a Metadata API call here? If you want to change the _definition_ of a field, you must be using the Metadata or Tooling APIs, and note that you're using a very old API version - the picklist data structures have changed.

Comment: I note you appear to be setting the picklist as an array. A picklist is a string, for the purpose of setting it, where the value matches one of the picklist entry API names.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everyone who suggested the solution.

I figured out the problem with the help of the colleague.  Turned out the field `Type` was not enabled for `Event` object in Salesforce for my account.  We went into account and enabled the field.  After that the following code worked:

```
try {
        sfdcEventRecord.set("Type", "your own personal type");
    } catch (SalesforceException ex) {
        if (SalesforceException.handle(ex)) {
            logger.warn("processSfdcEvent: can not set Type field [meetingUuid=%s]: %s", meetingUuid, ex.getMessage());
        } else {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
```